# Resources from ResourceDictionary accessible but Styles are not

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm hoping to create a WPF User Control Library with reusable controls for my many projects to save time recreating them every time (something I've found myself doing).

So I:

- Created a WPF User Control Library, and created a `ThemeDark.xaml` file to contain common colour keys and styles.
- Created a separate regular WPF project in the same solution so that I can test the controls in an actual window.
- Added a project reference to the User Control Library.
- Added a `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries` into the `App.xaml` which references the theme file from the other project.

**The problem**: I can access and use the `SolidColorBrush` keys from the theme file just fine in the testing project, but for some reason IntelliSense can't see the `Style`s (which all have keys).

I also can't seem to use the `pack://application:,,,/` method of referencing the `ResourceDictionary` in `App.xaml`; it only accepts the filename. This was originally set through the Properties panel -> Source -> Browse, however I have tried a few different formats, all to no avail. It also doesn't seem to notice that `ThemeDark.xaml` is in a `Themes/` directory within the User Control Library project.

So - How does one properly reference a `ResourceDictionary` from a WPF User Control Library project and be able to use *all* resources (including Styles)?

DarkTheme.xaml (inside user control library project):

[image: DarkTheme.xaml]

App.xaml (inside testing project):

[image: App.xaml]

Resulting behaviour (very strange - `SolidColorBrush`es available but `Style`s aren't):

[image: Result]

Comment: If the resourcedictionary is from another dll, you will need to add  pack:// to the uri to merge it, won't work otherwise. From my experience, if you use in your app resources defined in another module, intellisense will not recognize them, and will keep marking them as  unresolved. There is a solution to this, but it involves creating your own resourcedictionary class and have your own logic to load them in your app. That way you could add an if(IsDesignTime) condition to app.xaml.cs to load them so intellisense could find them.

Comment: You need to specify the source to be `Themes/ThemeDark.xaml`. To use dictionary across projects, you need to use pack URI. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/merged-resource-dictionaries?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: As mentioned in the post, the pack:// uri doesn't fix the problem. Using `Source="pack://application:,,,/Themes/ThemeDark.xaml"` I get "An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary".

Comment: That is because you didn't add the project to the uri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I had removed the spaces from the project's *namespace*, but not from the *assembly name*.

Once that was fixed I was able to use `Source="pack://application:,,,/MyControlLibrary;component/Themes/ThemeDark.xaml"`
MyControlLibrary isn't the actual name! ;)